# Getting permutation of a string using nested loops

Tags: java, permutation

I have written a recursive method using nested loops to print all permutations of a given string.It prints all the permutations but more than once can someone figure out the problem and what to change in conditions to solve this?

```
public static String swap(String x,int a,int b){
    char list[]=x.toCharArray();
    char tmp=x.charAt(a);
    list[a]=list[b];
    list[b]=tmp;
    return new String(list);
}
public static void perm(String x,String base){
    if(base.length()==3)
        System.out.println(base);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
        for(int j=i;j<x.length();j++){
            String tmp=swap(x,i,j);
            perm(tmp.substring(1),base+tmp.charAt(0));
        }
}
```

Example:
Input :"abc".
Output: 
abc
acb
abc
bac
bca
bac
cba
cab
cba
abc
acb
abc
acb
abc
acb
abc
acb
abc.

Comment: Could you include input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @bhspencer added that

Comment: where's the rest of the code for the perm method?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis It is all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the modified version I did based on your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abc";
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    perm(chars, 0);
}

public static void swap(char[] x, int a, int b) {
    char tmp = x[a];
    x[a] = x[b];
    x[b] = tmp;
}

public static void perm(char[] x, int idx) {
    if (idx == x.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            System.out.print(x[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = idx; i < x.length; i++) {
        swap(x, idx, i);
        perm(x, idx + 1);
        swap(x, idx, i);
    }
}
```